# Calling View by using absolute path from Controller Action Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I am using Asp.Net MVC4 .I have my HomeController in my root Controller folder. and my view is in some different folder(~/Folder1/FolderB/View1.cshtml)

How can i access my view from HomeController.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Below Solution :

```
public ActionResult TestAction()
{
  // You can access view from any folder
  return View("~/Folder1/FolderB/View1.cshtml");
}
```

Hope This will help !!